# Why is my IIS 301 permanent redirect rewrite persistent / not reverting?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-4, https, iis-10, url-rewrite-module

sorry my bad English. I had searched everywhere and tried what I found articles but didn't working all parts.
I had olddomain.com without ssl cert. And I bought new domain as newdomain.com with ssl.

I want to:

1. Redirect all olddomain.com to newdomain.com with https
2. Redirect https://olddomain.com to https://www.newdomain.com
3. Redirect all http or https://newdomain.com to https://www.newdomain.com

I apply following codes in web-config. Its working correctly when I tried in server. But didn't work google console and in my any browsers include mobile.

```
 <rewrite>
    <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="Force WWW, SSL and NewDomain" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
              <match url="(.*)" />
              <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(http://)?(www)?olddomain\.(com)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="(https://)?(www)?olddomain\.(com)" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^[^www]" />
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
              </conditions>
              <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

In this case, when I try to:

1. olddomain.com --> https://olddomain.com or [www.olddomain.com](http://www.olddomain.com) --> https://olddomain.com Doesn't work.
2. olddomain.com/tr/ --> https://www.newdomain.com/tr/ Working correctly.
3. newdomain.com/ --> https://www.newdomain.com/tr/ Working correctly.

Here is the real one for you :
When I open this address, http://www.gurmeliquid.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya it's change and redirect this address and not correctly working https://www.gurmeliquid.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya

But, I open this address, http://www.gurmeliquid.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-cesitleri
its change and redirect this addres correctly https://www.gurmeliquids.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-cesitleri

So, what happened, where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have **local caching issues**.

Your `web.config` looks fine to me & [http://www.gurmeliquid....](http://www.gurmeliquid.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya) is redirecting correctly for me to [https://www.gurmeliquids...](https://www.gurmeliquids.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya).

Request:

```
GET /tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya HTTP/1.1
Host: www.gurmeliquid.com
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://www.gurmeliquids.com/tr/elektronik-sigara-likit-antalya
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
Date: Wed, 06 Oct 2021 13:32:06 GMT
Content-Length: 186
```

I believe the cause is that you've been testing out multiple `web.config` variations which returned a `301 Moved Permanently` previously for *other* endpoints.

Your browser(s) will permanently "cache" this and your only way around it is to redirect to the same endpoint *twice* server-side or clear local cache.

Clearing cache differs for various browsers but for Chrome, open up the "Network" tab in developer tools (F12), load the page and then right-click on the request and select "Clear browser cache". Refresh and hopefully, it'll work.

If that doesn't work, your only way is a redirect loop.

When the browser detects a redirect loop, it'll attempt to clear its cache and get the latest URI location from the server so try redirecting back twice in case your browser has cached previous development `web.config`s pointing to other endpoints.

Try clearing cache in your browser first before resorting to a temporary double redirect to fix your issue.

Comment: I think you are right. Some urls are working correctly now. I can clear cache no problem but, I actually I want change url from google search console. I change url here. Before when I ask that question, It's not working any url. Now I tried. It's seems some urls are working correctly. I must wait google search console clear itself caches. I will write updates.

Comment: Ah, Google Search Console takes time, give the Google crawler time - otherwise your code is fine :)

Comment: Google will crawl your website eventually, give it a few days and it should pick up on your website

Comment: Thank you so much.